# Scroll GridView immediately to given offset

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, android-viewpager

I've got a `ViewPager` with fragments which contain `GridViews`. I want to save the scrolling position and offset of current `GridView` and give these parameters to appearing GridView when swipe the pager. I do it like this:

1. In GridView's `onScroll` event I just save this parameters values in activity.
2. When the page is going to be changed (`onPageScrollStateChanged`: `state == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`) I pass saved position and offset to adjacent fragments which apply given values to `GridViews`.

**Activity class**

```
public class JournalActivity extends FragmentActivity implements JournalMarksFragment.OnMarksGridScrolledListener {
    private ListView mGroupList;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private JournalPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private int mFragmentGridPosition;
    private int mFragmentGridOffset;
    private int mCurFragmentIndex;

    public ListView getGroupList() {
        return mGroupList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_journal);

        mGroupList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.group_list_view);
        mGroupList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.journal_student_item,
            new String[]{"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4",
                    "Item 5","Item 6","Item 7","Item 8",
                    "Item 9","Item 10","Item 11","Item 12",
                    "Item 13","Item 14","Item 15","Item 16",
                    "Item 17","Item 18","Item 19","Item 20",
            }));

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.journal_pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new JournalPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
                if(state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    List<Fragment> frags = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
                    for (Fragment frag : frags) {
                        if (frag instanceof JournalMarksFragment) {
                            JournalMarksFragment fragment = (JournalMarksFragment) frag;
                            if(fragment.getIndex() != mPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                                fragment.setMarksGridScrolling(mFragmentGridPosition, mFragmentGridOffset);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarksGridScrolled(int scrolledPosition, int offset) {
        mFragmentGridPosition = scrolledPosition;
        mFragmentGridOffset = offset;
    }
}
```

**Fragment class**

```
public class JournalMarksFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    public static final String ARG_INDEX = "index";

    private OnMarksGridScrolledListener mGridScrollListener;
    private GridView mHeaderGrid;
    private GridView mMarksGrid;
    private ListView mLinkedGroupList;
    private int mIndex;
    private int mPrevGridScrollingState;

    public JournalMarksFragment() {
        super();
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return mIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mGridScrollListener = (OnMarksGridScrolledListener) activity;
        mLinkedGroupList = ((JournalActivity) activity).getGroupList();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mGridScrollListener = null;
        mLinkedGroupList = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mIndex = getArguments().getInt(ARG_INDEX);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_journal, container, false);
        mHeaderGrid = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.journal_header_view);
        mMarksGrid = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.journal_marks_view);

        String[] headerData = new String[]{"Section 1", "Section2", "Section 3", "Section 4", "Section 5", "Section 6"};
        String[] marksData = new String[120];
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i < marksData.length; i++) {
            marksData[i] = String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(5));
        }
        mHeaderGrid.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.journal_mark_item, headerData));
        mMarksGrid.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.journal_mark_item, marksData));

        mMarksGrid.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                mLinkedGroupList.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                return false;
            }
        });
        mMarksGrid.setOnScrollListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    //here is the problem
    public void setMarksGridScrolling(int position, int offset) {
        /*mMarksGrid.setSelection(position);
        mMarksGrid.smoothScrollByOffset(-offset);*/
        mMarksGrid.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, -offset);
    }

    private int calculateGridOffset(GridView grid) {
        int offset = (int)getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        final View first = grid.getChildAt(0);
        if (first != null) {
            offset -= first.getTop() + 1;
        }
        return offset;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int state) {}

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        if (mGridScrollListener != null) {
            int position = mMarksGrid.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int offset = calculateGridOffset(mMarksGrid);
            mGridScrollListener.onMarksGridScrolled(position, offset);
        }
    }

    public interface OnMarksGridScrolledListener {
        public void onMarksGridScrolled(int scrolledPosition, int offset);
    }
}
```

**Pager Adapter**

```
public class JournalPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public JournalPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        JournalMarksFragment fragment = new JournalMarksFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(JournalMarksFragment.ARG_INDEX, i);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 20;
    }
}
```

Actually my implementation of this stuff works fine in most of cases - I scroll `GridView` then swipe page and get adjacent `GridView` with the same scrolling position and offset. But when I scroll my `GridView` to very bottom FIRST and then swipe page, I get the weird behavior of applying scrolling offset: the appearing `GridView` gets really random scrolling offset every new swipe. Only after 5-6 swipes `GridView` gets correct values.

I'm not sure, but I suppose it's the problem around GridView's method `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, offset, duration)` I used before, because the `setSelection(position)` method works correct - using is I always get my GridView scrolls to correct position. And all I need is to finish scrolling to remaining offset. I tried using `smoothScrollByOffset(offset)`, but it doesn't want to work correctly. Also, I don't need smooth scrolling. So, is there any way to perform immediate (like setSelection method) scrolling of GridView to given offset?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forunately, I've found the solution. As I said before, the `setSelection` method of `GridView` is very useful and correct working, so I use it to scroll to the given position. Then in theory I should invoke `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop` but it doesn't work fine - in some cases it just stops scrolling in the middle. The solution here is to wrap this invocation into `Runnable` and pass it to `View.postDelayed(action, delay)` with 1 ms delay.  I'm completely satisfied with this solution.
Code:

```
public void setMarksGridScrolling(final int position, final int offset) {
    mMarksGrid.setSelection(position);
    mMarksGrid.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mMarksGrid.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, offset, 1);
        }
    }, 1);
}
```